# html content changing position when I zoom?

Tags: html, css, position

I've searched for answers to my problem but none of the results actually solved it.

**Here is what my content looks like at 100% zoom:**

[image: Here is pic before zoom in]

**Here is what my content looks like after zooming in:**

[image: this is what happens after zoom in]

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #F2F4F7 ;
}
div {
    max-width: 900px;
    min-height: 590px;
}
#div1{
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 590px;
    background: url("1234.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute;
}
#div2{
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 0px;
    background-color: #E7E8E9 ;
    float: right;
    width: 365px;
    height: 590px;
    position:static;
}
```

Why does my content change position when I zoom?

Comment: Wayne Werner thank you for clarifying my question. Problem resolved. NBO's answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour as your *html* and *body* element widths stay 100%;

You can try to wrap both *div* elements in the same container with fixed width.

Comment: Thank you for quick respond.